# Error with a documentclass in Latex

Tags: latex

I want to write something in dfgproposal documentclass.

This is the code:

```
\documentclass[RAM]{dfgproposal}

\begin{document}

\begin{proposal}

a

\end{proposal}

\end{document}
```

But, I get this error after *pdflatex ptoposal*.

> (./proposal.bbl) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty)) (./proposal.out) (./proposal.out) proposal: Reading Project Data (./proposal.pdata) ! Undefined control sequence. \prop@proposal ...RGE Acronym: {\prop@gen@acronym }}[.2cm] {\large \today ... l.45 ?

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please include your error in the question as text.

Comment: click the grey "edit" link under your question and paste the error  there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class you're using requires more substance before it can properly compile. As such, a simple `proposal` environment with some content won't do. My suggestion would be to start with the simple example [`proposal.tex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/proposal/examples/simple-proposal/proposal.tex) provided by the [`dfgproposal` class](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/dfgproposal).

Here is an extract of the example, stripped down into something small/manageable:

[image]

```
\documentclass[RAM]{dfgproposal}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\WAperson[id=miko, 
           personaltitle=Prof. Dr.,
           birthdate=13. September 1964,
           academictitle=Professor of Computer Science,
           affiliation=jacu,
           department=case,
           privaddress=None of your business,
           privtel=that neither,
           email=m.kohlhase@jacobs-university.de,
           workaddress={Campus Ring 1, 28757 Bremen},
           worktel=+49 421 200 3140,
           worktelfax=+49 421 200 3140/493140,
           workfax=+49 421 200 493140]
           {Michael Kohlhase}

\WAperson[id=gc,
           personaltitle=Dr.,
           academictitle=Senior Researcher,
           birthdate=14. April 1972,
           affiliation=pcg,
           department=pcsa,
           privaddress=None of your business,
           privtel=that neither,
           workaddress={PCG Way 7, Hooville},
           worktel=+49 421 0815 4711,
           workfax=+49 421 0815 4712,
           email=gc@pcg.phony]
           {Great Communicator}

\WAinstitution[id=case,acronym=CASE,shortname=CASE,
                url=http://jacobs-university.de/ses/case,
                partof=jacu]
               {Center for Advanced Systems Engineering}

\WAinstitution[id=jacu,acronym=JacU,
               url=http://jacobs-university.de,
               streetaddress={Campus Ring 1},
               townzip={28759 Bremen},
               countryshort=D,
               country=Germany,
               type=University,
               logo=jacobs-logo.png,
               shortname=Jacobs University]
               {Jacobs University Bremen}

\WAinstitution[id=pcsa,
                           url=http://pcg.phony/sa,
                           partof=pcg,shortname=Science Affairs]
               {Science Affairs}
\WAinstitution[id=pcg,acronym=PCG,
                           url=http://pcg.phony,
                           countryshort=D,
                           streetaddress={Seefahrtstrasse 5},
                           townzip={23555 Hamburg},
                           shortname=Power Consulting]
               {Power Consulting GmbH}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}\color{red}\huge
  This mock proposal is just an example for \texttt{dfgproposal.cls} it reflects the 
  current DFG template valid from October 2011.
\end{center}

\urldef{\gcpubs}\url{http://www.pcg.phony/~gc/pubs.html}
\urldef{\mikopubs}\url{http://kwarc.info/kohlhase/publications.html}
\begin{proposal}[PI=miko,
  pubspage=mikopubs,
  thema=Intelligentes Schreiben von Antr\"agen,
  acronym={iPoWr},
  acrolong={\underline{I}ntelligent} {\underline{P}r\underline{o}sal} {\underline{Wr}iting},
  title=\pn: \protect\pnlong,
  totalduration=3 years,
  since=1. Feb 2009,
  start=1. Feb. 2010,
  months=24,
  RM=36,RAM=36,
  discipline=Computer Science, 
  areas=Knowledge Management]

\begin{Summary}
  Writing grant proposals is a collaborative effort that requires the integration of
  contributions from many individuals. The use of an ASCII-based format like LaTeX allows
  to coordinate the process via a source code control system like Subversion, allowing the
  proposal writing team to concentrate on the contents rather than the mechanics of
  wrangling with text fragments and revisions.
\end{Summary}

\section{Additional information \deu{(Ergänzende Erklärungen)}}

Funding proposal XYZ-83282 has been submitted prior to this proposal on related topic XYZ.
\end{proposal}

\end{document}
```